# Java:What's reason to define a character like this?

Tags: java, types, char, character, primitive

Ok, just 2 lines of code. I understand the first line. What's the meaning of the second line and when and why do i have to use this line?

```
char c = 'x';
Character C = new Character(c);
```

Please answer to all of the questions..(What's,when,why)

Comment: Note that there are between using primitives and wrappers/Objects.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239560/when-should-i-use-primitives-instead-of-wrapping-objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char` is a primitive type. `Character` is the wrapper to the primitive type, as you can see in the Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

> The Character class wraps a value of the primitive type char in an
>   object. An object of type Character contains a single field whose type
>   is char.
>
> In addition, this class provides several methods for determining a
>   character's category (lowercase letter, digit, etc.) and for
>   converting characters from uppercase to lowercase and vice versa.

Comment: It's useful in casting during reflections as well since you cannot cast the Object type to the primitive type.

Answer (score 4):

`Character` is a wrapper of the primitive type `char`. It allows you to use the primitive `char` in a more object-oriented way.

Answer (score 4):

Java provides a Class for every primitive type (int, char, long, float, byte, short, boolean and double) The ideia is to have this Class instead of the primitive type to operate where you need an `Object`.

```
Object a = new Integer(1);
Object b = new Character(c);
```

See an `ArrayList`, for example:

You cannot do:

```
ArrayList<boolean> list = new ArrayList<boolean>;
```

But you can do:

```
ArrayList<Boolean> list = new ArrayList<Boolean>;
list.add(new Boolean(true));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the Wrapper Class of the primary type char. As this is an Object you can use it like every other Object, for Example some Collection use Objects, or a Character could also be        null, whereas a char can not.

Answer (score 1):

The first line create a primitive `char` where as the second creates a `Character` object. You don't have to use one or the other. It depends on what you are doing with your code. Generally java will un-box primitives as needed.

Answer (score 1):

That is called a boxed primitive, and they're useful when, for example, you want to put primitives into a `Collection`. Since a collection has to hold objects, you can't just declare a `Collection<char>`, so you need to use a `Collection<Character>`.