# What is the difference between these casts? Which one is preferred?

Tags: java, casting

Hi I'm very new to Java and I wonder what is the difference between these two statements:

```
long statusId = (long)(Some_Valid_Cast);
```

and:

```
Long statusId = (Long)(Some_Valid_Cast);
```

Which one should be preferred for casting and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Long vs Integer, long vs int, what to use and when?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857812/long-vs-integer-long-vs-int-what-to-use-and-when)

Answer (score 3):

The first one casts to the primitive type `long`, and the second to an object of type `Long`. These are different- see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857812/long-vs-integer-long-vs-int-what-to-use-and-when) related question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want an object representation of a long, or just the number (the primitive) ?

Primitives (int, long etc.) can be interchanged with their object equivalents (`Integer`, `Long` etc.). If you use the object variants they can then be inserted in collections that normally take objects (e.g. `Map`, `List`, `Set`) and used wherever an `Object` is expected. I would, however, normally expect you to be using the primitive variant for most applications.

It's worth looking at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239560/when-should-i-use-primitives-instead-of-wrapping-objects) for more information on the pros/cons.

Answer (score 1):

**long** is primitive type and **Long** is Object type. Its based on your need. >=Java5 version , explicit type cast not required