# copying Integer Array to next activity

Tags: android

I have

```
Integer[] mainArray;
```

In one of my activity which was filled randomly with unique values.
Now I want this array to copied to next activity? 
How can be achieved? I have seen that there seems to be no option to carry it with

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putIntArray("key", mainArray);
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(b);
```

Comment: you have right code for sending Array to next Activity then what is issue ? yes u have one more operation by create a singleton class to share data between Application components

Comment: with above code, eclipse says :The method putIntArray(String, int[]) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, Integer[])

Comment: then just use Intent.putExtra for sending Integer array

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly what you need :

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putIntArray("key", mainArray);
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(b);
```

Just get the data from it on your other activity, 
 on onCreate() :

```
int data[] = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("key");
```

What is the problem?

There is a difference between `int` and `Integer` in Java.
You can find out more about it here : [What is the difference between an int and an Integer in Java and C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-c)

Comment: with above code, eclipse says :The method putIntArray(String, int[]) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, Integer[])

Comment: Please take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-c

Answer (score 0):

In the activity sending the integer array use:

```
intent.putExtra("array", mainArray);
```

In the activity receiving this integer array use:

```
int array[] = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("array")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Instead of integer array use arraylist.

```
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
 i.putIntegerArrayListExtra("name", arraylist);
 startActivity(i);
```

Other this integer arraylist to next activity

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("name");
```