# int[] and Integer[] arrays - What is the difference?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, int

Considering following basics:

1. Any `Object` lives only on heap,
2. Array IS-A `Object` and
3. `Integer` IS-A `Object`

I find myself difficult to answer such a simple question: Is there any difference between `int[]` and `Integer[]` **inside of JVM**? Or it makes sense only at "compile-time"?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a difference at run-time.

`int[]` is an array of primitive int values. `Integer[]` is an "object" array, holding references to Integer objects.

Most important practical difference: `int[]` cannot hold `null` values.

> But I'm still confused: does `int[]` store just a primitive values? If so - doesn't it mean that primitive types can live on heap without being wrapped?

`int[]` does store primitive types. And the array itself lives on the heap. However, those primitives are allocated as part of the array. They are not stored separately elsewhere on the heap. This is very similar to how a primitive field is part of an object instance: The object is on the heap, and its field is an integral part of that object (whereas for a non-primitive field, only the reference is stored inside the object and the target instance that reference points at is stored separately on the heap).

You could say the `int` is "wrapped" inside the array.

Comment: you can also assign null to array irrespective of the type it stores

Comment: yes, the array itself can be null. But not elements in a primitive type array.

Comment: @Thilo, thank a lot for the answer. But I'm still confused: does int[] store just a primitive values? If so - doesn't it mean that primitive types can live on heap without being wrapped?

Answer (score 10):

This image should help you to understand the difference:

[image]

[`int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is a *number*, it's a *primitive type*. 
[`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) is an *object*.

When you have an array of `Integer`s, you actually have an array of *objects*. Array of `int`s is an array of primitive types.

Since arrays are objects, they're allocated on the heap. If it's an array of `int`s, these `int`s will be allocated on the heap too, within the array.

You may find [this link](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.il/2008/08/java-int-versus-integer.html) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) is a class/object while [int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is a primitive type. Integer is a [wrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html) for int. If you need a *null* value to be stored, or need to use [collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), use Integer. You can do-

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

So, an array of primitive types are different from an array of integer objects.

Answer (score 1):

- Integer[] is an array (object) of objects
- int[] is an array (object)
  of primitives

Than there is a difference between Integer and int [summarized here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-and-c).