# What is the difference between int[ ] and Integer [ ]

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I was trying to reverse the order of an array and print it. I did this by moving each element into an ArrayList using a for loop decremented from the (array.length-1). Then I tried to use the 'arrayList.toArray(array)'method. I know it returns 'object [ ]' so i changed my 'int [ ]' to 'Integer [ ]' and it worked.

My question is what is the difference between an array 'Integer []' and 'int [ ]'

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //here i changed int [] to Integer []
    Integer[] arr ={ 4,3,5,7,8,2,9,1};
    System.out.println("array list \t :"+ Arrays.toString(arr)+"\n");
    System.out.println(" pos 1:   " + arr[1]);
    System.out.println("pos last: " + arr[arr.length-1]);
    System.out.println("*********************************");
    swapElements(arr);
    System.out.println("array list after  :"+ Arrays.toString(arr)+"\n");
    System.out.println("pos 1 after swap is:\t" + arr[1]);
    System.out.println("pos last after swap is: " + arr[arr.length-1]);

}
public static void  swapElements(Integer []array)
{ 
    ArrayList<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i =array.length -1;i>=0; i--)
    {

        array2.add(array[i]);

    }
    array2.toArray(array);
}
```

Comment: `Integer` is an object, `int` is a primitive, that's it.

Comment: Google is your friend, friend.

Comment: but why don't we just call every array Integer [] instead of int [] in any task

Comment: Integer is an object that wraps an primitive (int).    

    Integer[] arr ={ 4,3,5,7,8,2,9,1};

In this line the compiler is automatically doing some Auto-boxing(Changing int to Integer) for your int values 4,3,5 ...

Comment: It's a duplicate of [`int[]` and `Integer[]` arrays - What is the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18845289/2991525).

Answer (score 1):

Elements of `int[]` are by defualt initialized with value of 0, but the elements of `Integer[]` are by default initialized to null.

In some cases, you might need nulls (to denote nothing) instead of 0s.