# The difference between int[] and Integer[] and why are they treated differently?

Tags: java, arrays, boxing

I've got two pieces of code, in both the main focus is the method `Arrays.asList(T... a)`. 
In the first of them I input an `Integer[]`, in the second I input an `int[]` , and - this is the part that confuses me, in the two cases, the resulting `List<...>` is different:

```
Integer[] arrayBoxed = new Integer[10];
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arrayBoxed);
```

It's pretty short, and none of the values in arrayBoxed are set, but it works, and produces an `List<Integer>`.

```
int[] array = new int[10];
List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

In this case, for some reason, I get a `List<int[]>`, which is a pretty pathological construct.

Why is that?

The problem is, that given the similar input into `Arrays.asList`, I'd expect both of the functions to output the same (both code pieces are fully functional). However, one time the method returns `List<Integer>`, the other time `List<int[]>`.

Comment: Here some informations that may be useful for your research -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845289/int-and-integer-arrays-what-is-the-difference

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arrayBoxed); here, you are making a list of elements with type Integer. List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(array); here, you declare a list of elements with type 'array of int'

Comment: `T` can't represent primitive type so in case of `T...` for `in[]` `T` can't become `int` and closest available non-primitive type is array itself. So `List<T>` becomes `List<int[]>`.

Comment: Take a look at duplicate, especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1467940

Comment: One difference : Basically int is primitive type. and Integer is a wrapper class. when you are declaring variable with int, you can not assign null value to it.  But with integer , you can assign null value to it. This difference mostly helps in database when you want to store null values in column from java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` takes an array of reference types, not primitive types.

So, when you call `Arrays.asList(int[])`, the reference type taken is `int[]` (the array type), and that's why the result is `List<int[]>`.

`Integer` is a reference type, which explains why `List<Integer>` is the return type.