# What is the difference between Float and float in java?

Tags: java, variables

Can someone explain to me the difference between Float and float in java? Manythanks.

Comment: Google : Wrappers vs primitives Java.

Comment: See the java wrapper classes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class

Comment: It's like the difference between `int` and `Integer`, but this is less duplicated :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between an int and an Integer in Java and C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-and-c)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Float` is an object; `float` is a primitive. Same relationship as `Integer` and `int`, `Double` and `double`, `Long` and `long`.

`float` can be converted to `Float` by autoboxing, e.g.

```
float f=1.0f;
Float floatObject = f;
```

or explicitly

```
Float floatObject = new Float(f);
```

Initially primitives were retained alongside the object versions for speed. Autoboxing/unboxing was added with java 5 to facilitate conversion.

Answer (score 6):

Float is a class which wraps the primitive float.  In newer versions of Java, a feature called autoboxing makes it hard to tell that they are different but generally speaking, use float when you using the number to do calculations and Float when you need to store it in Object collections.