# Why can't I loop through the ArrayList

Tags: java

I wanted to make a simple prime number printer in java, and the last for loop was giving me an error.

```html
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  primeNumbers.add(1);
   for (int i = 2; true; i++){
    for(int j = 2; j <= i; j++){
     double a = i/j;
     if(a % 1 == 0 && i != j) primeNumbers.add(i);
    }
   }
   for (int value : primeNumbers) {
       System.out.println(value);
   }
 }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It's just the last for loop that is giving me the error

Comment: This is the comment section.  People are not always looking at this, so do not expect instant responses.  Now about your code... What is the error and can you post the stack trace if there is one?

Comment: `for (int i = 2; true; i++){` you have the boolean part of the for loop set as true and no where inside your loop do you have a break.  Therefore you loop will go forever and it will never exit and go onto the printing for loop.

Comment: This is because your `first` loop never terminates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the outer `for` loop is infinite (that is the last loop is unreachable). Change this

```
for (int i = 2; true; i++) { // <-- infinite loop
```

to something like

```
for (int i = 2; i < 1000; i++) { // 2 to 1000.
```

Comment: ok, now that I fixed it, my new code is import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  primeNumbers.add(1);
  for (int i = 2; true; i++) {
   for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
    double a = i / j;
    if (a % 1 == 0 && i != j) {
     primeNumbers.add(i);
     System.out.println(primeNumbers.get(i));
    }
   }
  }

 }
}                 


It still gives me an error though, and it says:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 2

Comment: @RoeiBurstein Because you tried to get the element at the index 3, even thought the list had only two elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to refer to `primeNumbers`, that is an `ArrayList<Integer>` with an `int`. It should be:

```
for (Integer value : primeNumbers) {
                System.out.println(value);
            }
```

`Integer` it's different than `int`. Look at this:

[What is the difference between an int and an Integer in Java and C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-and-c)

Comment: no it's not. look for something called "autoboxing"

Comment: @fukanchik I saw it now. Thanks for correct me! I'm learning Java and I didn't know that but I have a doubt, could be some problems attached to this "autoboxing"? I mean, it wouldn't preferable to use `Integer` instead of `int` and then not to force to the compiler to translate it?