# Transform a doWhile in a While loop

Tags: java, class, loops, integer

I have a problem with a task. I must transform the following doWhile loop into a While loop, so that the result of both loops is the same?
As you can see the type `Integer` is just in the doWhile loop. But what's the difference between type `int`. How do I solve this task?

doWhile loop:

```
public Integer a_doWhile(int x){
    int i = 0;
    Integer result;
    do {
        result = ++i*i;
    } while (result < x);
    return result;
}
```

My solution:

```
public Integer a_while(int x){
    int i=0;
    int result;
    while(result < x){
        result = ++i*i;
    return result;
    }
}
```

But my solution is wrong. It has to do sth with this "Integer", Can someone help me please? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

int and Integer are different representation of same thing. Int is primitive while Integer is object representation. This is discussed here [What is the difference between an int and an Integer in Java and C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-and-c)

You can convert you dowhile to while like this

```
public Integer a_While(int x){
    int i = 0;
    Integer result = ++i*i;
    while (result < x) {
        result = ++i*i;
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank youvery much Leadfoot!