# Why Netbeans complains about ambiguity while Intellij instead doesn't

Tags: java, intellij-idea, netbeans, kotlin, ambiguity

I have a kotlin math lib with the following `Vec2i` [class and primary constructor](https://github.com/elect86/glm/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/vec/_2/Vec2i.kt#L19):

```
data class Vec2i(override var x: Int, override var y: Int) : Vec2t<Int>()
```

Then `Vec2i` has also, among several secondary constructors, one which is supposed to intercept all the other [number types](https://github.com/elect86/glm/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/vec/_2/Vec2i.kt#L65):

```
constructor(x: Number, y: Number) : this(x.i, y.i)
```

Everything under Idea compiles and runs. I tested the artifact with a separate java project.

The same artifact doesn't run in a java project if I switch IDE, Netbeans complains about ambiguity between the two.

Why?

Edit: from some further analysis, it turned out Netbeans complains because one of coordinate was `int`, the other `Integer`.
Trying the same on Idea, it says:

> cannot resolve constructor

So, why calling a costructor with `(int, int)` or `(Integer, Integer)` is fine, but `(int, Integer)` doesn't resolved to the secondary constructor and provoke ambiguity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-and-c

Comment: Uhm, clear, if you want to answer, I'll accept that

Comment: not sure that is enough for an answer, I just thought it would help.

Comment: Well, at begin it seemed to help, but the fact that `(Integer, Integer)` works makes me confused.. I don't know how to explain that

Comment: The constructor has x: Number etc. Integer inherits from Number, so it gets treated as one 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: @hellyale, btw if you want to answer, I'll accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At [oracles documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) we see that `Integer` is an object that holds an `int`.

`int` is a primitive type, whereas `Integer` is an object.

The constructors you have allow for passing a pair of either type, but when you pass both the constructor does not know what to do.

For more information [this question](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) has a good breakdown.