# If statement doesn't work, the program enters directly the "else" statement

Tags: java, if-statement, mouseover

I am trying to write a program which detects "idle" status but I don't see the problem in my code. Could someone help me please with an useful tip? Here's my code:

```
package idlestatus;

import java.awt.MouseInfo;

public class Idlestatus {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Integer firstPointX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
        Integer firstPointY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
        Integer afterPointX;
        Integer afterPointY;
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            afterPointX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
            afterPointY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
            if (firstPointX == afterPointX && firstPointY == afterPointY) {
                System.out.println("Idle status");
            } else {
                System.out.println("(" + firstPointX + ", " + firstPointY + ")");
            }
            firstPointX = afterPointX;
            firstPointY = afterPointY;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: or use `int` not `Integer`.

Comment: Well yeah...It solved, thanks sir !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`If` is working but your condition is always getting `false`, because you are using `Integer` instead of primitive `int`. Note that when you use Object, compare them with `.equals()` method instead of `==`.

Therefore :

```
if (firstPointX.equals(afterPointX) && firstPointY.equals(afterPointY)) {
    //your code...
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java) for difference between `==` and `Object.equals()` method.

And as mentioned in comments, you can always use `int` for such purposes, instead of `Integer`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-and-c) for difference between `Integer` and `int`.

Comment: It was enough to use .equals instead of ==, also int for such purposes might be better. Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: Just did it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two objects memory addresses , which is `Integer` object(wrapper class).

```
if (firstPointX == afterPointX && firstPointY == afterPointY)
```

What you want to do is compare values in these two objects. To do that you need to use like below:

```
if (firstPointX.equals(afterPointX) && firstPointY.equals(afterPointY))
```

**Wrapper / covering classes:**

- There is a wrapper class for each primitive data type.
- Primitive types are use for performance reasons(Which better for your
  program).
- Cannot create objects using primitive types.
- Allows a way to create objects and manipulate basic types(i.e.
  converting types).

Exsample:

```
Integer - int
Double - double
```