# int or Integer in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I have seen many times in code that people use `int` or `Integer` to declare variable in beans. I know `int` is `datatype` and `Integer` is `wrapper class`.
My question is, in which condition `int` or `Integer` should be used and is there any advantage of either of them over another?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between an int and an Integer in Java and C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-and-c). Specifically, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/608/7151494) from there.

Comment: I think we should always use `int` by default, a primitive type has less cost than on object. Use an `Integer` object when you need the functionality of an object. e.g. function argument by reference or when you are returning an int and you want to have a case where the result can be null.

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always use `int`, pretty much.

`Integer` should rarely be used; it is an intermediate type that the compiler takes care of for you. The one place where `Integer` is likely to appear is in generics, as `int` is simply not legal there. Here is an example:

```
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int v = 10;
indices.add(v);
```

The above works: It compiles with no errors and does what you think it would (it adds '10' to a list of integer values).

Note that `v` is of type `int`, not `Integer`. That's the correct usage; you could write `Integer` here and the code works as well, but it wouldn't be particularly idiomatic java. Integer has no advantages over int, only disadvantages; the only time you'd use it, is if `int` is straight up illegal. Which is why I wrote `List<Integer>` and not `List<int>` as the latter is not legal java code (yet - give it a few versions and it may well be legal then, see Project Valhalla).

Note also that the compiler is silently converting your v here; if you look at the compiled code it is as if javac compiled `indices.add(Integer.valueOf(v))` here. But that's fine, let the compiler do its thing. As a rule what the compiler emits and what hotspot optimizes are aligned; trust that what javac emits will be relatively efficient given the situation.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, in which condition int or Integer should be used and is there any advantage of either of them over another?

Well, you should use the reference type `Integer` whenever you **have to**. `Integer` is nothing more than a boxed `int`. An Object with a single field containing the specified `int` value.

Consider this example

```
public class Ex {
    int field1;
    Integer field2;

    public Ex(){}
}
```

In this case field1 will be initialized with the value `0` while field2 will be initialized with `null`. Depending on what the fields represent, both approaches might be advantageous. If `field1` represents some kind of UUID, would you want it to be initialized with a zero value?

I wouldn't worry too much about the performance implications of Autoboxing. You can still optimize **after** you get your code running.

For more information take a look at the documentation

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html

Answer (score 0):

[`int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html#:%7E:text=int%3A%20By%20default%2C%20the%20int,value%20of%20232%2D1.) is a primitive type, a `value type` for number literals.

- it is used whenever and wherever you just want to do some basic arithmetical operation;
- it is a `value type`, so it's stored in the `Stack` area of the memory, hence operations on it are much faster;
- whenever it's needed, compiler implicitly and automatically casts back and forth (a.k.a Boxing and Unboxing) from `int` to `Integer` and vice versa;

[`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) is a *Class*, which is a `reference type` and you instantiate an Object of that type.

- you create an object of that class, which means, that you also have some methods and operations on that object;
- any time you do some arithmetic operation on the instance of `Integer`, under the hood, it's still implemented by `int` primitives, and it's just wrapped into box/container;
- it is a reference type / object, which is very important, as you can **Serialize** or **Deserialize** it;
- it also has some very useful utility factory methods, like `Integer.valueOf(..)` for example, to parse the String as an integer;
- it can be well used into declarations of the generic types and it, as a class, supports the hierarchy as well. For instance, it extends `Number`, and you can make use of this;
- it is stored in the `Heap` area of the memory.

Answer (score -1):

int is a primitive and Integer is an object .
From an memory footprint point of view , primitive consume less memory than object and also primitives are immutable (since they use pass by value ) .
Here is a good article on when to use what :
https://www.baeldung.com/java-primitives-vs-objects

Comment: Well, `Integer` objects are also immutable.

Comment: Pass by value does not imply immutability. Java is **always** pass by value. You don't create a new `int` and keep the previous one in the memory until GC collects it if you assign some different value to it.